# To remove last n lines from .asc file and plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a .asc file which looks like this(x and y columns)

```
48.069868   11993  
49.111533   11824   
50.153094   11325  
51.194551   11229  
52.235905   11318

Date and Time:                   Wed May 31 14:47:29 2017   
Software Version:              4.20.30007.0       
Temperature (C):              -60
Model:                        DU970_UVB
```

At the end of the file it has some string lines. So i plotting using matplotlib as

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

  plt.plotfile('600_1%_532e_Mo F1_80sec.asc', delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), 
           names=('col1', 'col2'), )
  plt.show()
```

Now if want to remove the last lines I can use lines[:-1], but:

1. Is it possible to remove the last n lines without specifying the numbers. I mean if python can read how many lines has string and it will delete only those lines.
2. I don't want to delete these lines permanently. Just for plotting the data points i want to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs carefully you can see that,

```
matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile(fname, cols=(0, ), 
plotfuncs=None, comments='#', skiprows=0, checkrows=5,   
 delimiter=',',names=None, subplots=True, newfig=True, **kwargs)
```

there is a optional parameter called as **comment**. What that means? It means read from the file yet skip those lines which are comments.

Also you stated that,

> I don't want to delete these lines permanently. Just for plotting the data points i want to remove them

So you don't want to delete them, yet you don't want to use them. So change them to comments!

**`my_file.asc`:**

```
48.069868   11993  
49.111533   11824   
50.153094   11325  
51.194551   11229  
52.235905   11318

Date and Time:                   Wed May 31 14:47:29 2017   
Software Version:              4.20.30007.0       
Temperature (C):              -60
Model:                        DU970_UVB
```

So logic is leaving out the numbers. Only convert lines that are strings into comments! How to do this use `re`.

```
tf = open('my_file.asc','r+')
d = tf.readlines()
tf.seek(0)
for line in d:
    s=re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]',line)
    if s:
        tf.write('#'+line)
    else:
        tf.write(line)
tf.truncate()
tf.close()
```

So what I'm doing is searching every line and if that line happens to start with string, then replace that `line` with `'#'+line`. (**change it into a comment)**. So after this, this is how your `my_file.asc` would look,

```
48.069868   11993  
49.111533   11824   
50.153094   11325  
51.194551   11229  
52.235905   11318

#Date and Time:                   Wed May 31 14:47:29 2017   
#Software Version:              4.20.30007.0       
#Temperature (C):              -60
#Model:                        DU970_UVB
```

You got what you wanted after that it's pretty simple. The same as your code. Here is the complete solution working solution

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

tf = open('my_file.asc','r+')
d = tf.readlines()
tf.seek(0)
for line in d:
    s=re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]',line)
    if s:
        tf.write('#'+line)
    else:
        tf.write(line)
tf.truncate()
tf.close()


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.plotfile('my_file.asc', delimiter=' ',comments='#', cols=(0, 1), 
           names=('col1', 'col2'), )
plt.show()
```

I just added `comments='#'` and voila! you got what you wanted without deleting those lines.
[image: Plot_Figure]

Comment: Thanks @s_vishnu that worked for me! But in the end it gives me string lines starting with #. Is it possible to remove them also , i don't require here, but simply asking it would be better if i can do that also.

Comment: After plotting you want to remove the `#` from the file?

Comment: Select the answer if it worked for you :) click the little tick below downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it with `plotfile` function but as I know `plotfile` uses function `csv2rec` ([docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec)). In your case you can do the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import csv2rec


def converter(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = csv2rec(
        "'600_1%_532e_Mo F1_80sec.asc'",
        delimiter=" ",
        names=("col1", "col2"),
        converterd={
            "col1": converter,
            "col2": converter,
        }
    )
    data = filter(lambda i: i[0], data)
    plt.plot(*zip(*data))
    plt.show()
```

If converter function can't convert value to float it returns `None`. So `data` will have `None` values for all non-convertable items. After that you can filter it.

Answer (score 0):

same as [`csv2rec`](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec) (which is the function called under the hood), `plotfile` seems to accept file handles, in addition to file paths (although not explicitly mentioned [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile.html)).

If you can afford storing your file to memory (read: you're not working with gigantic files), you could use [`StringIO.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) (Python 2.7) or [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) (Python 3).

`StringIO` is a file-like object where you can copy the content of your file, while applying additional logic (ie. skip the footer lines). Once produced this new object, you can pass it to `plotfile`. Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from StringIO import StringIO
# from io import StringIO

footerlines = 5
with open('example.asc', 'r') as fhandle:
    temp = StringIO()
    for line in fhandle.readlines()[:-footerlines]:
        temp.write(line)
# bring the pointer back to the beginning of the file-like object
temp.seek(0)

plt.plotfile(temp, delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), names=('col1', 'col2'))
plt.show()
```